# беды со студией

Tags: c++

[image: сама ошибка]

Вместе с этой вылазят ошибки(400+!) которые не находятся в моём коде который, в свою очередь, работает абсолютно исправно на  ideone.com. Беде не помогла даже неоднократная переустановка студии :(
Прошу помочь, т.к завтра дедлайн. Спасибо!

Comment: не нужно студию переустанавливать. Создайте новый проект в студии, проверьте, что это обычный плюсовый, а не CLI, и то, что он компилится. А дальше переносите свой код.

Comment: Тут пишут, что можно попробовать sdk установить: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12685202/how-do-i-get-crtdbg-h-file

Comment: я сильно сомневаюсь, что это нужно делать. Вряд ли ТС так далеко зашел.

Comment: А средства разработки для С++ установили?